# Can I open Blender internal files with python?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I want to open a file which is packed into the Blend-file with the `open()` function while the game is running.

Is it possible? And can I write files into it? Like open`("Test.blend/Text.txt", "w")` or something?.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109704/15543)

Comment: Use `bpy`
operator, that the best way ,documentation is usefull for the operator :D
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you run the game by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> in Blender, you can simply use the `bpy` module and access Blender's data while the game is running.

If you don't want to depend on Blender, you're limited to the [LibLoad](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bge.logic.html#bge.logic.LibLoad) function. However, this doesn't support text datablocks. Writing to blend files is also not possible in that case. IMO it'll be much easier to read and write directly to files on the filesystem, rather than packing them inside blend files.

Comment: Sure but it also has to work with the standalone player. And generally its a bad idea to use bpy within the game engine

Comment: That's rather situation dependent. I chose the BGE for my project *because* it allows me to use the bpy module. If this was a requirement, you could have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: But its generally no good idea

Comment: If with "generally" you mean "if you want your game to run in the standalone player" you're correct, but I would hardly call that "generally". The BGE is also used for simulations, where recording the result of the physics engine and/or simulation data to Blender's FCurves is very powerful. Also I'm a former BGE developer, I kind of know what I'm talking about ;-)

Comment: Yes you're right. :) But in most cases bpy isn't used

Comment: Please mark this answer as 'Accepted', or let me know in which way it's not good enough.

Comment: I'm still not able to open internal files in Blender Game Engine

Comment: What you want is not possible, as I point out in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bpy module and functions do not work in standalone player mode.
suggest using write()or open() methods.