# How to search through multiple Blender files and filter objects by collection?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

This is similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/how-to-search-through-multiple-blender-files-to-find-a-specific-object) except I need to also filter my objects by collection.

I have a large group of Blend files. I need to go through each one and check if all the objects (and their children) in a collection called "room" match a specific naming scheme. The objects outside the "room" collection have to be ignored. If any of these objects don't match the naming scheme, I need to flag that blend file at the end for review.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is, but the closest example I found was that question linked above. However, because there's no documentation for blendfile, I can't figure out how to filter objects by collection before listing their names. I'm open to using BAT or BPY, but as far as I can tell BPY isn't suited to bulk tasks like this.